# How to create axes in matlab GUIDE

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I want to implement the following code using `matlab GUIDE`:

```
axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(image1);
axes(handles.axes2);
imshow(image2);
```

As I am very new to GUIDE so I am having no idea how to do this. Any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open guide selecting empty gui
2. Drag and drop two axes objects anywhere in the figure.
   Right clicking on any axes object and seeing it properties allows to set size, position, and name of the object.
   Guide always generate figure file in parallel with .m file containing all callback functions, among them function to be called on opening the gui (just before it is visible) -you can put you imshow() code there...
   The whole thing is very intuitive, and has a great help provided by matlab.

Comment: Can you kindly guide me what commands would I use in matlab .m file to call GUI or what would be the exact syntax.

Comment: To call existing giu, you just need to type name of the gui in command line/your m file. To start guide, just type guide in matlab command line.